# vba vlookup in 2 different workbooks till the end of the previous line

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have 2 excel files:

```
barkod.xlsx

campaign.xlsx
```

I need to make a vlookup command in barkod.xlsx. I want to lookup The column E in barkod.xlsx through the campaign.xlsx - columns A:B.
I also tried to double drag the formula till the last value of E at the end. The result will be written in  column F in barkod.xlsx.

I tried with this codes :

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook




'## Open all workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mammadov.ali\Desktop\macros\barkod.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mammadov.ali\Desktop\macros\csv.csv")
Set q = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mammadov.ali\Desktop\macros\campaign.xlsx")


'## Clear the workbook first:
y.Sheets("csv").Range("A:M").Clear


'## Insert the column in the barkod file:
x.Sheets("barkod").Range("F1").EntireColumn.Insert

'## Insert the column header in the barkod file:
x.Sheets("barkod").Range("E1").Offset(0, 1).Value = "Discounts"


With x.Sheets("barkod").Range("F2")
.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], [campaign.xlsx]Sheet1!RC[-5]:RC[-4], 2, 0)"
.AutoFill Destination:=x.Sheets("barkod").Range("F3")

    End With
```

I am struggling with this almost 2 days. Any help would be highly appreciated.
What I get is it does not show me the correct result and it only does the vlookup for : A2:B2 only. Also it occurs an error during the run.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to create the formula with VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to:

- remove "xlsx" and "R"s from `[campaign.xlsx]Sheet1!RC[-5]:RC[-4], 2, 0)"`
- have destination range of `AutoFill` method encompass source range

as follows:

```
With x.Sheets("barkod").Range("F2")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], [campaign]Sheet1!C[-5]:C[-4], 2, 0)"
    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(2) ' this will autofill F2 and F3
End With
```

if you want to AutoFill as many cells in column F as not empty values in column E, then you would use:

```
    .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Offset(, -1).EntireColumn))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such precise correct answer. The only thing which I face is , when I run the macro Excel becomes unresponsible. Something causes this but not sure what.